# Capture image with OpenCV without GUI(on console linux)

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I am using console linux and I have a camera capture application. I need to capture an image without GUI(The camera should start and capture some images, save it to disk and close). The following code works well on my laptop but doesn't start on console. Any suggestions?

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera


Mat frame;
    namedWindow("feed",1);
    for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;   // get a new frame from camera
    imshow("feed", frame);
    imwrite("/home/zaif/output.png", frame);    
if(waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is the most lame problem description ever. now what is going wrong ?

Comment: I mean if I run this on my console, it is not capturing any images or feed is not running but works on my laptop. I need to make changes so that it starts->capture a image->close.

Comment: nothing wrong with the code, i'd say.  2.4.6 had a problem with videocapture and gcc, that's why there is 2.4.6.1

Answer (score 2):

After the release of OpenCV 2.4.6 there were [bug fixes for video capture on Linux](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/2b2e02166ef81973e040ff36e9812d8e83599380).  Go straight to 2.4.6.2 and you should get the fixes.  Specifically, [this revision](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/f77d1f57eee1a8b9160b5bd2e312736bd6294b9e) is probably the relevant fix for you, although there were a number of other revisions pertaining to video capture on android that might effect Linux compilation too.

Comment: the links are broken